# Does restarting a PC clear the browser cache?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, caching, web, browser-cache

I have an old application running on locked-down PCs which are used as wall displays. They all point to a URL using IE11 to get a web page view. The problem is, when the Web Page updates, even if it is refreshed, a cached version is displayed.

If the PC is reset will it clear the cache?

Comment: Probably not, no.

Comment: That is an interesting situation. Can you change the URL? What HTTP headers were sent to IE with page that is currently cached?

Answer (score 1):

To reduce some potential caching issues, it's best to have Internet Explorer set to request the latest version of the page rather than relying on a cached copy.  To do this:

1. From the **Tools** menu choose **Internet Options**.
2. On the General tab, under Browsing history, click **Settings**.
3. Under "Check for newer versions of stored pages" make sure "**Every time I visit the webpage**" is selected.
4. Click the **OK** button.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Prakash. Unfortunately because the PCs are locked-down I can't access the browser settings to clear the cache normally. I'd have the same problem with this solution.